# How to remove firebase custom domain?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, custom-domain

I have created firebase hosting site and it connected to my domain(`www.mydomain.com`). But I want to remove this firebase hosting site and I want to get back my previous site on my domain. I deleted my custom domain from my firebase console so it disconnected. However when I go to my domain it says `Site Not Found`. How I get my previous site?

Comment: You managed to solve it, how did you do it? I have the same problem.

Comment: @PacoZevallos Remove the TXT records which you added previously below to your DNS provider to verify you.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to change your `DNS nameservers` on your domain provider back to the providers original IP's.

Here's some explanation from [GoDaddy](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/change-nameservers-for-my-domains-664).

Also, it always takes some time to propagate the changes. So it might be that you only need to wait.